# html_table doubles value of columns

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape wiki table with this code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
my_url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Australian_Open_men%27s_singles_champions"
mytable <- read_html(my_url) %>% html_nodes("table") %>% .[[4]] 
mytable <- mytable %>% html_table()
```

The problem is that in the table returned in both columns with names (champion & runner-up) values are doubled. well not exactly doubled, it looks like two forms of presenting name/surname in different order and with comma once. It does not look like that on the original wiki page only "name surname" is visible there. Why does it happen and how to get rid of it? I need those columns to contain 'name surname' only.

```
head(mytable)    
Year[f] Country                    Champion Country                         Runner-up Score in the final[4][14]
    1    1969     AUS      Laver, RodRod Laver[b]     ESP       Gimeno, AndrésAndrés Gimeno             6–3, 6–4, 7–5
    2    1970     USA     Ashe, ArthurArthur Ashe     AUS           Crealy, DickDick Crealy             6–4, 9–7, 6–2
    3    1971     AUS   Rosewall, KenKen Rosewall     USA           Ashe, ArthurArthur Ashe             6–1, 7–5, 6–3
    4    1972     AUS   Rosewall, KenKen Rosewall     AUS Anderson, MalcolmMalcolm Anderson        7–6(7–2), 6–3, 7–5
    5    1973     AUS Newcombe, JohnJohn Newcombe     NZL             Parun, OnnyOnny Parun        6–3, 6–7, 7–5, 6–1
    6    1974     USA Connors, JimmyJimmy Connors     AUS               Dent, PhilPhil Dent   7–6(9–7), 6–4, 4–6, 6–3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`htmltab` could be used to scrap these Wiki tables.

```r
library(htmltab)

#data cleaning steps
bFun <- function(node) {
  x <- XML::xmlValue(node)
  gsub("\\s[<†‡].*$", "", iconv(x, from = 'UTF-8', to = "Windows-1252", sub="byte"))
}

df1 <- htmltab(doc = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Australian_Open_men%27s_singles_champions", 
              which = 4,
              rm_superscript = F,
              bodyFun = bFun)         #this function is not required if you are executing the code from Mac
head(df1)
```

which gives

```
#  Year[f] Country      Champion Country        Runner-up Score in the final[4][14]
#2    1969     AUS  Rod Laver[b]     ESP    Andrés Gimeno             6–3, 6–4, 7–5
#3    1970     USA   Arthur Ashe     AUS      Dick Crealy             6–4, 9–7, 6–2
#4    1971     AUS  Ken Rosewall     USA      Arthur Ashe             6–1, 7–5, 6–3
#5    1972     AUS  Ken Rosewall     AUS Malcolm Anderson        7–6(7–2), 6–3, 7–5
#6    1973     AUS John Newcombe     NZL       Onny Parun        6–3, 6–7, 7–5, 6–1
#7    1974     USA Jimmy Connors     AUS        Phil Dent   7–6(9–7), 6–4, 4–6, 6–3
```

and

```
df2 <- htmltab(doc = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Wimbledon_gentlemen%27s_singles_champions", 
              which = 3,
              rm_superscript = F,
              bodyFun = bFun)         #this function is not required if you are executing the code from Mac
head(df2)
```

gives

```
#  Year[d] Country        Champion Country            Runner-up   Score in the final[4]
#2    1877  BRI[e]    Spencer Gore     BRI     William Marshall           6–1, 6–2, 6–4
#3    1878     BRI     Frank Hadow     BRI         Spencer Gore           7–5, 6–1, 9–7
#4    1879     BRI    John Hartley     BRI Vere St. Leger Goold           6–2, 6–4, 6–2
#5    1880     BRI    John Hartley     BRI      Herbert Lawford      6–3, 6–2, 2–6, 6–3
#6    1881     BRI William Renshaw     BRI         John Hartley           6–0, 6–1, 6–1
#7    1882     BRI William Renshaw     BRI       Ernest Renshaw 6–1, 2–6, 4–6, 6–2, 6–2
```

Comment: Thanks. That solves the problem of doubled names, but unfortunately creates problem of special characters. I get MoyĂˇ instead of Moyá or MeÄŤĂ­Ĺ™ instead of Mečíř. I guess it is about fixing `gsub('â€“', '-', gsub('Â', '', x))` inside `bfun` but i don't think i can do it.

Comment: what about this table [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Wimbledon_gentlemen%27s_singles_champions). it's quite like the one in the question, but some entries in column 'champion' contain strange character like: ‡, ◊, †. Your code at the moment fails to read them (NAs in data.frame).

Comment: These strange characters are the content of original Wiki table so these are legitimate ones. For the table in your new link you don't need any encoding conversion so try this `library(htmltab) ; df <- htmltab(doc = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Wimbledon_gentlemen%27s_singles_champions", 
              which = 3,
              rm_superscript = F)`

Comment: Well @Prem I'm affraid some encoding is necessary. Otherwise we return to the issue of some values getting 'corrupted' like DrobnĂ˝ instead of Drobný, John HartleyÂ instead of John Hartley and so on.
I was also hoping for method universal for both those tables (and two others) so that i can use in in for loop.

Comment: Oh I see! Actually I replied to your comments from Mac and there you don't require any encoding conversion so I had suggested not to use it while scraping the link provided in your comment. For windows machine I have updated the answer which you can use in a loop.